# how i could remove this space from python code

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
mon = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
]

while True :
    ask_date = input ('Date:')
    try:
        month,day,year= ask_date.split('/')
        if int(month) >=1 and int(month) <=12 and int(day)>=1 and int(day) <= 31 :
            break

    except :
        try :
            old_month,old_day,year=ask_date.split(' ')
            for i in range(len(mon)):
                if old_month == mon[i]:
                   month =i+1
            day = old_day.replace(',',' ')
            if (",") not in old_day :
                pass
            elif int(month) >=1 and int(month) <=12 and int(day)>=1 and int(day) <= 31  :
                break

        except :
            print()
            pass

print(f"{year}-{int(month):02}-{int(day):02}",sep='',end='')
```

Here are some examples of inputs with expected and actual outputs:

```
:) outdated.py exists 
:) input of 9/8/1636 outputs 1636-09-08 
:) input of September 8, 1636 outputs 1636-09-08 
:) input of 10/9/1701 outputs 1701-10-09 
:) input of October 9, 1701 outputs 1701-10-09
--->  :( input of " 9/8/1636 " outputs 1636-09-08 expected "1636-09-08", not "1636 -09-08"
:) input of 23/6/1912 results in reprompt 
:) input of 10 December, 1815 results in reprompt
:) input of October/9/1701 results in reprompt 
:) input of 1/50/2000 results in reprompt 
:) input of December 80, 1980 results in reprompt
:) input of September 8 1636 results in reprompt
```

By doing it manually I'm getting the expected output for 9/8/1636, but after verifying with `cs50 extension` it's getting an extra space. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you specifying *sep* and *end*? Also you don't make any attempt to remove irrelevant/unwanted whitespace from the input string

Answer (score 0):

When your input is " 9/8/1636 " here's what happens:

You split on '/' which gives you 3 tokens - i.e., ' 9', '8' & '1636 '

Note the leading space in the first token and the trailing space in the last.

You pass the first and second tokens to *int()* That function ignores any leading or trailing whitespace so you get 9 & 8

However, you do not convert the third token to *int* - i.e., you use it as a string and that string has a trailing space.

If you expect the year to be a valid int then you could do this:

```
print(f"{int(year)}-{int(month):02}-{int(day):02}")
```

Another option would be to strip leading and trailing whitespace from the user input as follows:

```
ask_date = input('Date:').strip()
```

...then you wouldn't need to change anything else in your code

Comment: tyy i got that later !!